# Preventing ProGuard from changing access modificators

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I got several classes with a public constructor, which are only accessed dynamically by Java.

I had to use -dontshrink, so he doesn't remove several methods which lead to NoSuchMethodExceptions. Now he starts to set those public constructors to private for some reason (since he thinks nobody uses it?).

Anyone knows why this happens and/or how to prevent this?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview)?

Comment: Yes but this leads to me having alot of other classes not obfuscated so I want to avoid this.

Comment: I meant something like `-keep class * { public <init>(...); }` which should keep all public constructors for all classes (if my memory serves me well). You can narrow this by using the `extends` or `implements` keywords after the `*` (if possible for your use case). Or you can whitelist particular classes in a similar way. Good luck!